# Firebase database only updates one data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Context:

I just did a sample program that will get the score of a user and store them in the firebase database. It works well but the problem I am having is that when the score is already stored there and I use the app again it overwrites the previous data.

In other words I can only store one data at a time. How can I make it so that it will store multiple data and not have other data be overwritten?

Codes:

```
  private FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   private DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("Score");
```

This is the code for the submit button where when the button is pressed then the data will be stored.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String Score = mScoreView.getText().toString();
         root.setValue(Score);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `push()` method which will generate a random id in the database. First get a reference to the root node:

```
private FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("Score");
```

Then when adding do the following:

```
root.push().setValue(Score);
```

Comment: Thanks bro. didn't know it would be that simple but nevertheless, I would never have figured that one out I just kept retyping and switching out some codes earlier.